# What new meaning does "letztendlich" contribute?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=letztendlich&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=0) the word "letztendlich" is a very new invention in German language. Meanwhile this word is very present in all kinds of communication, be it formal or informal.

Is there any meaning this word has that an older term could not express?

I am asking because I believe this is a filler word that you can use to sound important without saying anything. "Ich denk mal *letztendlich* kommt es doch darauf an, dass man irgendwie grad mal eben eher mehr so das nicht wirklich Falsche tun müsste, um wirklich total nachhaltig gehandelt zu haben". Blabla. Typische Zeitverschwendung für den Zuhörer und "letztendlich" kommt letztendlich fast immer bei solchen Gelegenheiten vor. Es gibt keine anderen (diese Frage ausgenommen). Oder? (Useless stutter, a typical waste of time for the listener, and "letztendlich" always is a key part of such occasions (with this question being an exception). Right?)

So the question is:

**What meaning does the young term "letztendlich" contribute that any other more classic term cannot express?**

P.S.: The same seems to be true for "schlussendlich". This term is less popular, but has risen even steeper in last decade´s usage than "letztendlich".

Comment: *Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp*: http://canoo.net/blog/2007/01/20/letztendlich/

Comment: Ja nee letztendlich frag ich ja nicht ohne Grund _hier_ :) aber: danke.

Comment: Did you switch between languages or is the whole German part considered as example? Please use ">" to designated text as example and translate those parts that are not examples to English (or everything else to German).

Comment: @TheBlastOne: Ich gehe davon aus, wenn jemand fragt, daß er eine Antwort haben möchte; der verlinkte Text beantwortet die Frage (die Dopplung dient der Hervorhebung/Verstärkung). Also, was ist statt dessen der Grund, ausdrücklich _hier_ zu fragen?

Comment: @chirlu: we want people to find the answer on German Language & Usage when [searching via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=letztendlich+german+meaning) (on position 5 here). A comment with an external link is not a vaild answer very much like a link-only answer will not be valid too. We would like to encourage people to not only make up a link collection here but also write good answers. These may also include excerpts quoted from an external source.

Comment: @Takkat: Schon recht, aber 1. das ist die Perspektive der Site, nicht eines fragenden Nutzers, 2. der Link kann von jemandem beim Schreiben einer richtigen Antwort genutzt werden. Ich habe deshalb die Beschwerde über den Link immer noch nicht verstanden.

Comment: @chirlu: ich vertrete hier die Perspektive von SE. Wir wollen eine Q & **A** Seite sein, kein Forum. Deshalb werden Posts die nur Links enthalten nicht so gerne gesehen. Links können Aussagen stützen aber sie verrotten (fast) alle mit der Zeit, und dann ist es extrem mühsam, die Inhalte wieder zu reparieren, zudem wenn keine Zitate vorliegen. Dann bleibt oft nur noch der Papierkorb und das ist sehr schade. Dann lieber ein Copy & Paste mit ordentlicher Quellenangabe.

Comment: @Takkat Was für SE gut ist, muss ja nicht für die Ratsucher gut sein, oder? Wenn Google eine SE-Frage, in der nur mit einem kurzem Zitat auf eine das Thema erschöpfend behandelnde .edu-artige Seite verwiesen wird, zuerst aufführen sollte, wäre das dann gut oder schlecht für die Ratsucher? Derzeit stehen die Chancen, dass GLU aus dem Beta-Stadium hinauswächst, bei weniger als 50/50. Soweit es überhaupt in meiner Macht steht, die Chancen von GLU auf Fortdauer zu erhöhen, tue ich das jedenfalls, indem ich informative Antworten und Kommentare schreibe, ohne auf Suchmaschinen-Optimierung zu achten.

Comment: @chirlu Weil ich hier mehr verschiedene Meinungen von Leuten, die ich (zumindest beim Sachgebiet, um das es hier geht), achte, und deren Meinung mich interessiert. Dr. Bopp kennischnisch, und die Kommentatoren dort gehen zum Teil stark in die Richtung "spiegel-online-Schnacker". Nur meine Meinung.

Comment: Letztlich, schließlich, endlich (weniger) werden ähnlich benutzt. Letztendlich ist eine Verdopplung der Bedeutung und ergo eine Betonung.

Comment: Manchmal ist es irgendwie grad mal eben am Ende des Tages tatsächlich vielleicht egal, ob man "schlussendlich" oder "effektiv" oder "letztendlich" benutzt, wenn es nicht erforderlich ist, denn wie man sieht, kann ich ebenfalls auch beliebig in gewisser Weise und dennoch tatsächlich Monstersätze sagen, die nichts ausdrücken, aber viele Worte verlieren. "Letztendlich" ist da nur ein mittelaltes Beispiel. "Tatsächlich", "irgendwie", "in gewisser Weise" und "ebenfalls" sind jüngere Beispiele für Neudeutsch-blabla, das die deutsche Sprache verwässert und unpräzise macht. Jedenfalls letztendlich.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A language is always changing. New words come, old words go. So it is not a question of what a new word contributes … just like in fashion.

I modified your n-gram to include [letzten Endes](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=letztendlich,%20letzten%20Endes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=0&share=). The result is very interesting. You can see an even faster rise of **letzten Endes** followed by a steady decline. **Letztendlich** is just hip at the moment. Maybe because it is shorter. Maybe because it has no Genetive. Maybe because it spares people the second of doubt as to whether to write it with a capital or not.
However, chances are that **letztendlich** will have its peak someday and then a new star will be born.

At first I though it could be **letztlich** … but no … Google n-gram shows that it has overstayed its welcome already. But **effektiv** is to be watched out for ;)

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to know how you all judge this kind of hip word usage.

Comment: And the winner is: [schließlich](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=letztendlich%2Cletzten+Endes%2C+letztlich%2C+schlie%C3%9Flich&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=0&share=)

Comment: and "schlussendlich" I guess

Comment: @TheBlastOne: `schließlich` ist ein Link. Folgt man ihm kann man leicht ein `schlußendlich` ergänzen und beobachten, dass dieses unter der Wahrnehmungsgrenze bleibt.

Comment: I don't like the idea of schlußendlich being an innovation in any sense. You are right, though, in that my question implies new words need additional meaning to become popular. Unfortunately, they don´t.

Comment: That word is maybe just reflecting how fast our communication needs to be today - By saying "letztendlich", we tell the receiver that we are sparing them a lot of argumentation and discussion and make it very obvious that this one is the last and final argiment they need to understand to be convinced...

Answer (score 2):

"Letztendlich" of course can be used as a simple and meaningless filler. But it also can express the wish to bring an end to a long discussion as being "the final conclusion" and rendering everything said before less important.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

> This book (that you need to read for the exam) has 500 pages, but of
>   all those 500 pages, only this 1 is really relevant.

German translation would be

> Dieses Buch hat 500 Seiten, aber letztendlich ist nur diese Seite
>   wichtig.

So in this sense, it expresses that all the rest is negligible.

I suppose you could see it as some kind of operator-precedence.

For example you have a SQL-query:

```
SELECT * FROM WHATEVER_TABLE WHERE (1=1) 
AND CONDITION 1 
AND CONDITION 2
AND CONDITION 3
AND CONDITION 4
AND CONDITION 5
OR CONDITION 6
```

And because you forgot the bracket beween

```
AND 
(
    CONDITION 5
    OR 
    CONDITION 6
)
```

letztendlich, only condition 6 is relevant.

Comment: Disagree. Translation would be "Dieses Buch (das Du für Deine Prüfung lesen musst) hat 500 Seiten, aber von diesen 500 Seiten ist nur diese eine wirklich relevant." No need for "letztendlich". And your SQL assumption is also false: If any of those conditions has side-effects, the result might be different from computing only CONDITION 6 as opposed to computing them all. (SQL does not do short-circuit evaluation of Boolean terms.)

Comment: Wenn Condition 1 bis 5 alle zum gleichen Wahrheitswert auflösen, der im Gegensatz zu Condition 6 steht, dann ist nicht nur Bedingung 6 relevant. Während das Beispiel in sich falsch ist ist es aber m.E. richtig gemeint. @TheBlastOne: Das `nur` ist die Verdopplung des letztendlich, die dieses überflüssig macht, ja. Ohne dieses hätte Quandary Recht.

Comment: @TheBlastOne: Good point - while writing this I was tinking of a specific example that involved condition 6 always being true - but in the general case, you're of course right; and nice case that condition 5 could be true and condition 6 false - but I think you got the point, even when you disagree. Also on a word-to-word translation you'r right, you can translate it like that, but - while gramatically corret - it would sound a little bit dodgy.